# contact form error un defined

Tags: php, syntax-error, undefined

I am using the code below to send an email and attach an image with a short description.

I am getting the error below and I don't understand why:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\form\index.php on line 64 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012146120{main}( )..\index.php:0 ">**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$human = intval($_POST['human']);
$from = 'Demo Contact Form';
$to = 'example@domain.com';
$subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
$body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
$errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
$errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}
//Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
if ($human !== 5) {
$errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
}
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
$result='<div class="alert alert-success">
Thank You! I will be in touch
</div>
'; } else { $result='
<div class="alert alert-danger">
Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.
</div>
'; } } } ?> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap contact form with PHP example by BootstrapBay.com.">
<meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
<title>Bootstrap Contact Form With PHP Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1 class="page-header text-center">Contact Form Example</h1>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_post['name']); ?>"> <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>
                    $errName
                </p>
                ";?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_post['email']); ?>"> <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>
                $errEmail
            </p>
            ";?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?>
            </textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>
            $errMessage
        </p>
        ";?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>
        $errHuman
    </p>
    ";?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's good to start with the problem description when posting a question rather than just a wall of code.

Comment: first time posting problem don't have experience with this

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains exactly what the issue is. The name variable is not set when you first load the page, because nothing has been posted yet. So of course, $_POST['name'] does not exist. That's what the php error is telling you. You'll need to replace all of your $_POST inside the form with this:
`<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); } ?>` so you won't see those errors anymore. Also, you should be using $_POST, not $_post.

Alternatively, you can put `error_reporting(0);` at the top of your file and it will hide all of these warnings. However, it's not reccomended because if there is a real error you won't know what it is until you remove that line.

Comment: now <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?> these and <?php echo $result; ?> is also giving error that is 
(Notice: Undefined variable: errName in C:\wamp\www\form\index.php)

Comment: why it says undefined variable ?

Comment: Everything nice and stuff, but I'd recommend NOT turning off error reporting but instead fix the errors

Comment: i need help please help